# Verbosity of MSBuild Copy Command

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

In an MSBuild task, you can set the overall verbosity, but what I'd really like to do is set the Verbosity of just the 'Copy' command.  It prints out a line for every file it's copying in the "normal" verbosity setting, which in my case is thousands of overly-detailed lines.

I don't see any documentation for such an attribute on the [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) task, so I'm wondering if there's another way... or if people just ditch the built in copy task and use robocopy with their own flags.

Comment: My exact same question. Perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own Copy task, adding an optional Verbosity parameter.

Comment: This is what I wound up doing, roughly.  I actually grabbed the latest version of MSBuild Community Tasks ( http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ ) which has a robocopy task, which offers the ability to skip logging files and directories.  It also has a number of other features (mirroring, retries, etc) which make it much nicer than the default Copy task.

Comment: Not a very good answer because it doesn't explain how to do such a thing nor link to an explanation.

Comment: Just for verbosity, it doesn't make any sense to write a custom task. Not sure why MS didn't add this support, when they actually have it for Robocopy

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own build logger. Add copy task to a specific target and filter build mesages from that specific target(s).

[Here is nice example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.loggerverbosity.aspx) of custom logger.
You have to pass /logger parameter with your custom logger to MSBuild command line.

Comment: would be nice if you stated how to use it.

Comment: Doesn't work. You can add messages, not take away messages destined for the logger and stdout.